# Java making a txt file

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to write content on a text file using java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4362456/how-to-write-content-on-a-text-file-using-java)

Is it possible to make use java to save text in a textfield as plain text, if so how?

Comment: Did you mean to say saving text in a textfield or text file?

Comment: You might want to search the site before asking, this has probably been answered 100 times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, get the text from the text field and save it in a file.

```
String text = textField.getText(); //get the text from the text field
BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("your_absolute_file_path"));
writer.write(text); //write it in the file
writer.flush(); //flush the write-buffer
writer.close(); //close the writer (and the file)
```

I am missing the `try/catch/finally` and the `import` statements here for brevity. But you should stick the `close()` in `finally` if `writer` is not `null`.

Comment: How exactly would I do this, I'm relatively new to java and don't know how to do IO things

Comment: Also take a look at File API http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/File.html

Answer (score 1):

It is possible. Take a look at the [Basic I/O tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/file.html). You are going to need a [`FileWriter`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html).

Answer (score 0):

using the FileWriter or FileOutputStream(for binary output)

P.S. Always remember to .close() the FileWriter after usage.
if you forget to close the filewriter the output might not show up.

By the way, using the BufferedWriter requires .flush() every "output".